# Loop through variable amount then split and wrap

Tags: html, jquery

I have a form in which I want to order the different fields in a `<div>`.

I managed to loop through the first elements and wrap those but I cannot figure out the next part.
In the HTML you see I managed to wrap the first 6 elements into `<div class="naw-wrapped">`. I need to skip the 'Left/Right/Both' element and wrap the remaining `<p>`. Now the amount of the remaining elements may vary per form but it's always an even number.
I would like to split these remaining elements and wrap in 2 divs:
(for readability I removed most of the content)

```
<form class="cart" action="">
    <div class="naw-wrapped">
        <p>
            <label>First name</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Last name</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Phone</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>E-mail</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Date of birth</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Notes</label> 
            <textarea ></textarea>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product-options-wrapped">
        <p class="option-left-right">
            <label>Left/Right/Both</label> 
            <select>
                <option>Left</option>
                <option>Right</option>
                <option>Both</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p class="product-option-element">
            <label>Porto Left</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p class="product-option-element">
            <label>Color: Left</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p class="product-option-element">
            <label>Venting: Left</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p class="product-option-element">
            <label>Porto Right</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p class="product-option-element">
            <label>Color: Right</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p class="product-option-element">
            <label>Venting: Right</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
    </div>   

    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

jQuery for the first part:

```
var $span = $(".cart > p");
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 6) {
        var $div = $("<div/>", {
            class: 'naw-wrapped'
        });
        $span.slice(i, i + 6).wrapAll($div);
    }
$(".cart > p").addClass('product-option-element');
var $optionsdiv = $("<div/>", {
    class: 'product-options-wrapped'
});
$(".product-option-element").wrapAll($optionsdiv);
$(".product-option-element:first").removeClass("product-option-element").addClass("option-left-right");
```

I need to know how to select only the remaining `<p>` without the ones in `<div class="naw-wrapped">`. And how to loop, split and wrap for these remaining elements. All elements in 1 `<div>` then skip 1 and split + wrap. Any suggestions on how to execute such split and wrap?

Idealy it would look something like this:

```
<form class="cart" action="">
    <div class="naw-wrapped">
        <p>
            <label>First name</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Last name</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Phone</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>E-mail</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Date of birth</label> 
            <input>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Notes</label> 
            <textarea ></textarea>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="product-options-wrapped">
        <p class="product-option-element">
            <label>Left/Right/Both</label> 
            <select>
                <option>Left</option>
                <option>Right</option>
                <option>Both</option>
            </select>
        </p>

        <div class="options">
            <p class="product-option-element">
                <label>Porto Left</label> 
                <input>
            </p>
            <p class="product-option-element">
                <label>Color: Left</label> 
                <input>
            </p>
            <p class="product-option-element">
                <label>Venting: Left</label> 
                <input>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="options">
            <p class="product-option-element">
                <label>Porto Right</label> 
                <input>
            </p>
            <p class="product-option-element">
                <label>Color: Right</label> 
                <input>
            </p>
            <pclass="product-option-element">
                <label>Venting: Right</label> 
                <input>
            </p>     
        </div>
    </div>
           

    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

UPDATED: Added class to the remaining `<p>` elements and wrapped those in the `<div class="product-options-wrapped">` as suggested by Master Silver.
With this I was able to give this first element a different class.

All that remains is to find a way to split the variable amount of `<p class="product-option-element">` and wrap those in 2 `<div class="options">`

Comment: For future reference, please include the *original* HTML input (ie. before any transformations) and the *output* HTML in the question before you submit it.

Comment: Apologies, do you mean put the HTML before the script is run? Then also the HTML after script ran? Thank you for your comment, still learning the ropes of posting proper questions on SO. Excuse my ignorance

Answer (score 1):

After giving a class to all remaining elements it was just a matter of dividing the amount of elements and wrap those in an element which was already answered on a different question. Thanks @Master Silver for the suggestion of adding classes. This made it alot easier.

Solution I used:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var $span = $(".cart > p");
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 6) {
        var $div = $("<div/>", {
            class: 'naw-wrapped'
        });
        $span.slice(i, i + 6).wrapAll($div);
    }
    
    $(".cart > p").addClass('product-option-element');
    
    var $optionsdiv = $("<div/>", {
        class: 'product-options-wrapped'
    });
    $(".product-option-element").wrapAll($optionsdiv);
    $(".product-option-element:first").removeClass("product-option-element").addClass("option-left-right");
    
    var $options1 = $("<div/>", {
        class: 'options-1'
    });
    var $options2 = $("<div/>", {
        class: 'options-2'
    });

    var $currentoptions = $(".product-option-element");    
        half = Math.floor($currentoptions.length/2);
    $currentoptions.filter(function(i){ return i < half; }).wrapAll($options1);
    $currentoptions.filter(function(i){ return i >= half; }).wrapAll($options2);
  });
```

```css
.naw-wrapped{
background: blue;
}
.product-options-wrapped{
background: red;
}
.options-1{
background: green;
}
.options-2{
background: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="cart" action="">
    <p>
        <label>First name</label> 
        <input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Last name</label> 
        <input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Phone</label> 
        <input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>E-mail</label> 
        <input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Date of birth</label> 
        <input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Notes</label> 
        <textarea ></textarea>
    </p>
    
    <p>
        <label>Left/Right/Both</label> 
        <select>
            <option>Left</option>
            <option>Right</option>
            <option>Both</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Porto Left</label> 
        <input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Color: Left</label> 
        <input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Venting: Left</label> 
        <input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Porto Right</label> 
        <input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Color: Right</label> 
        <input>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Venting: Right</label> 
        <input>
    </p>        

    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to give the p elements you want to select with your script their own CSS class in the first place. If you can not do that, the other option would be a really messy code, which will not work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've given a class to the remaining elements and wrapped those already. Only thing remaining is to split variable amount of elements and wrap those.

Comment: Sure, I'm glad I could help.